# Drawing a simple GWT Column Chart in Java

Tags: java, gwt, column-chart

I am just playing with GWT charts but I am not quite understanding how it works.

I want to draw a simple column chart with Book Names on x-axis and Number of Books on y-axis. Here is the code.

```
DataTable table = DataTable.create();
ColumnChart columnChart;

table.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Book 1");
table.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Book 2");
table.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Book 3");

table.addRows(3);
table.setValue(0, 0, 23);   
table.setValue(1, 0, 65);
table.setValue(2, 0, 23);

columnChart.draw(table, options);
add(columnChart);
```

This isn't working and the screen comes blank. I've set the chart size and everything in the `options`variable. Am I missing something?

Comment: may be you have to set row names too, have you checked example here https://code.google.com/p/gwt-charts/wiki/GettingStarted, called draw after adding widget to the panel

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have loaded the `ChartLoader` API first.

```
ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {
    // draw your charts in here
}
```